# Allow users of a certain group to run a command without sudo

Tags: linux, passwords, sudo

I know how to edit /etc/sudoers so that I can run a command as sudo without having to enter my password, however is there a way of allowing a program to be run completely without sudo, by all users of a group. (The programs I want to run is "mount" and "umount").

Comment: What is your OS? Are you trying to mount a NTFS partition, EXT partition, or optical drive?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Suppose I wanted to add a group of users who are allowed to run `mount` and `umount` without passwords. 
So I first want to add a group called "anyname"

```
sudo groupadd anyname
```

Next we need to edit the `/etc/group` and add the users

```
anyname:x:407:
```

will be present ,hence append users you want to add the users seperated by commas.

```
anyname:x:407:user1,user2,...
```

Now we need to configure sudo to allow members of the "anyname" group to actually invoke the  `mount` and `umount` commands.

You just need to add the following lines to /etc/sudoers

```
%anyname ALL=NOPASSWD: /sbin/mount, /sbin/umount
```

Now `sudo mount` wont ask password but since it is a pain in the butt typing sudo all the time, we can avoid it by dong the following:

I can create the following script called "/usr/bin/mount" (and similar script for umount)

```
#! /bin/sh
sudo /sbin/mount $*
```

To make this slightly more secure, We might want to change the ownership of these scripts to the "anyname" group.

```
chgrp anyname /usr/bin/mount /usr/bin/umount
```

and then make them executable only for the group "anyname"

```
chmod g+x /usr/bin/mount  /usr/bin/umount
```

**EDIT**:Depending on the OS you are using please check where mount and umount commands are located. It might be in /bin/ instead of /sbin.So you might have to make necessary changes

**IMPORTANT**:  BTW don't run the script on Arch based systems where all of the  bin folders are symlinked with each other.

Comment: Thanks. I actually have implemented using a global .bashrc, that contains a function mount that looks like this: mount { sudo mount $* }